# How do you Calculate Hours from the Beginning of the Year in PHP

Tags: php, countdown, hour

I Was Just Wondering How do you Calculate Hours from the Beginning of the Year in PHP 7.1

It's for a countdown clock that is precise

Comment: google php time difference in hours

Comment: Have you looked at http://carbon.nesbot.com?

Comment: PHP5.1 Not exactly on the bleeding edge of things are you. That does not sit well with your SO Handle. Maybe `Last Millenia Software` would be more appropriate

Comment: I would think of date_diff() (datetime->diff)
But you ask it for an ancient version of php and date_diff is only around since php 5.3: only 8 year ago

Comment: sorry, i meat 7.1, not 5.1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can just do:

```
$diff = date_create()->diff(new DateTime("first day of January ".date("Y")));
$hours = $diff->format("%a")*24 + $diff->h;
```

As requested here's a way to handle daylight savings:

```
$transitions = (new DateTimeZone(date_default_timezone_get()))->getTransitions();

$thisYearsTransitions = array_values(array_filter($transitions, function ($v) {
     return substr($v["time"],0,strlen(date("Y"))) == date("Y");
}));
if (count($thisYearsTransitions) == 2 && date_create($thisYearsTransitions[0]) < date_create() && count($thisYearsTransitions)>0 && date_create($thisYearsTransitions[1]) > date_create()) {
    $hours = $hours + ($thisYearsTransitions[0]["offset"]-$thisYearsTransitions[1]["offset"] > 0?1:-1);
}
```

What this would do is get the DST transitions for this year and if the current date falls after the first and before the second transition it will add/subtract an hour (depending on timezone). Not sure if this would work, have not tested it, but it should.

Comment: but that's PHP 5.3+. TS is using 5.1

Comment: @IvoP I think you're an update behind

Comment: ah : I see TS upgraded his php from 5.1 to 7.1 a minute ago

Comment: Might be nice to add how to handle a daylight savings shift in there if using localised timezones as well

Comment: @MarkBaker Added something, not very confident about it but it might work.

Comment: @apokryfos - yeah! It adds a nice challenge, especially if you have to consider northern and southern hemispheres, where the order of transitions (forward/backward) is reversed :)